# props.deleteComments not a function

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm following some code from a guide and I'm getting that error.

In my App.js I have:

```
deleteComments = async (commentId) => {
try {
  await axios.delete(`/comments/${commentId}`);
  const comments = await this.getComments();
  this.setState({ comments });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
};
```

CommentsList component

```
const CommentsList = (props) => {
const comments = props.comments.map((comment) => {
return (
  <Comment
    {...comment}
    deleteComments={props.deleteComments}
    key={comment.id}
  />
 );
});
```

Comment component where I call the function.

```
import React from 'react';

const Comment = (props) => {

const deleteComments = () => {
 props.deleteComments(props.id);
 };

 return (
  <div>
   ...
  <div>
    <button onClick={deleteComments}>Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
 );
};
```

Comment: CommentList doesn't get `deleteComments` prop passed. Show how you use it.

Comment: The prop isn't the deleteComments={props.deleteComments}?

Comment: but how does `deleteComments` get into props? Did you pass it to `CommentList`?

Comment: Oh ok, I understand where I went wrong and fixed it and now it's working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite obvious that `CommentList` doesn't get `deleteComments` prop passed. You need to pass it:

```
<CommentList deleteComments={deleteComments} />
```